# Add value and shifting rows in data frame

Tags: r, dplyr

I have one data frame which contain data like table below

```
MY_DATA<-data.frame(structure(list(MY_DATA = c(10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 
                                               100)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L)))
```

[image]

But my intention is change this table like table below, where actually instead of 10 I need to add 0 and shift all other numbers (10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80 and 90) and omit 100 like table below.

[image]

So can anybody help how to solve this problem and make table like pic above ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
> library(dplyr)
> MY_DATA$MY_DATA = lag(MY_DATA$MY_DATA, default = 0)
> MY_DATA
   MY_DATA
1        0
2       10
3       20
4       30
5       40
6       50
7       60
8       70
9       80
10      90
```

Answer (score 1):

```
MY_DATA<-data.frame(structure(list(MY_DATA = c(10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L)))
MY_DATA <- MY_DATA - 10
```